# How to create a daily calendar event using event kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, repeat, eventkit

I am having a event starting from june 1st to june 10th daily 10 am to 5 pm.After creating the event programatically it needs to add in calendar from june 1st to 10th in between 10 to 5 only.I don't want to enable the all day option.I want to use repeat daily option.And it needs to show in the dates given and time mentioned in blue colour (how event will display).

Answer (score 0):

[Create an instance of `EKEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW9) for the event, and an instance of [`EKRecurrenceRule`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKRecurrenceRuleClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) that describes the way the item repeats. Add the rule to the event using the `-addRecurrenceRule:` method from `EKCalendarItem` (which `EKEvent` inherits).

The color used to display the event is determined by the calendar, not by the event. If you must use a certain color, it's probably best to create a new calendar.